# C++ linker error when building multi-file project in Atom

Tags: c++, header-files

I am a total beginner in C++ and I'm trying to learn how to add header files to the main. I have 3 files in the same folder (main.cpp, add.cpp, add.h)

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h"

int main()
{
  std::cout << add(3,4);
  return 0;
}
```

add.cpp:

```cpp
#include "add.h"

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

add.h:

```cpp
int add(int x, int y);
```

Whenever I run this from the atom g++ compiler, I get the following error: in function `main':<br/>main.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference toadd(int, int)' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Can someone tell me what mistake am I making?

Comment: You didn't link the two object files together.

Comment: perfect, how do i do that ?

Comment: Set up a build system. This isn't always easy, which is why a more integrated build environment helps considerably. Up to you though! There's many options from `make` to `cmake` to other even more exotic types.

Comment: Could you suggest another enviroment, or link a way to do it with make ?

Comment: For macOS XCode is a great place to start, or on Windows, and possibly Linux, there's Visual Studio Community. They can be a bit involved to get going with, but it's more a case of learning the UI than some arcane build macro system like you get with `make` or `cmake`.

Comment: Bit of handy reading: [How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work). If you know what the steps are it'll be easier to figure out how the steps map to the tools atom supplies.

Comment: `make` is a method that does work, but search for a "make template" that comes close to what you need, and work from there as a basis.

Comment: Check me on this because I'm old. Atom is a development system?

Comment: Its an IDE, but you guys helped a lot and I got it running on Visual Studio.

Comment: Groovy. There should be some configuration page that you can use to tell it to link together the files. With visual studio, if you create the file with VS, it automatically adds it. If you create the file with another tool, you have to add the file (right click and select add) in the solution explorer.

Comment: Atom is an extensible text editor. It is not an Integrated Development Environment. If it were, this question would not have been asked.